# Selenium Webdriver locator(using java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

My locator for a button is not working. for that i can not go further. i tried xpath, cssSelector, ID. None of these worked. I upload the code. I am new at selenium. The last command is not working.

```
public class Upload {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    driver.get("http://888.b7omc88t.io/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //code for boomcast portal login

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/form/div[1]/input")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("fatima@ssd-tech.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/form/div[2]/input")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("1234");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/form/div[3]/button")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[4]/ul/li/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"smbscheduleobdStep2\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/input")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/input")).sendKeys("01791719879");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[3]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)")).click(); // This line is not getting executed

}
```

HTML of the button :

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-right">
    <button id="smbscheduleobdStep3" type="button" class="btn btn-block">Saved files</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it give any error? If possible, share the html code of the elements.

Comment: Your code has a lot of poor absolute xpath locators. Please fix them since they are brittle. Also the css selector you have used is brittle. Please add the HTML for better debugging and locator selection.

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 text-right"><button id="smbscheduleobdStep3" type="button" class="btn btn-block">Saved files</button></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if your locator works by Development tools in FF
2. Locator can be simplified to `By.cssSelector("#smbscheduleobdStep3")`
3. Check if your element isn't in frame, if so, you need to switch in it by using `driver.manage().switchTo().frame()`.

And of course can be used WaitDriver as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to click on the *Button* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the button to be clickable and you can use the following line of code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
// other code lines
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-block' and @id='smbscheduleobdStep3' and contains(.,'Saved files')]"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks ..It worked. I am facing another problem selecting a drop down.

Comment: the HTML is <select id="smbschedulecaller_id" name="callerid" class="form-control"><option value="">Select Caller ID or Long Numbers</option><option value="09612773831">09612773831</option></select>

Comment: @Nissan Please raise a new question as per your new requirement, StackOverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.